# How to remove each indivicual div once number inside it reaches 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following elements in HTML:

```
<li class="myDiv">15</li>
<li class="myDiv">20</li>
```

and this jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".myDiv").each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
        var number = $this.html();
        $this.html(parseInt(number) - 1);

    })
}, 1000);
```

I am grabbing the number inside of the div and making it into a number, then I am substracting one every second.

**How can I delete each individual div once the value inside that div reaches 0?**

I have this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thedarklord1939/kwMqu/) that substracts every number inside of the div.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove or http://api.jquery.com/detach

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you can use `.text(...)` here instead of `.html(...)`.  Using `.html(...)` for dealing with what should be strings of digits is like using a sledgehammer to swat a fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".myDiv").each(function (idx, elem) {

        var numb = parseInt( $(elem).html(), 10) - 1;

        if (numb === 0) {
           $(elem).remove();
        }else{
           $(elem).html(numb);
        }

    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwMqu/3/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".myDiv").each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
        var number = $this.html();
        $this.html(parseInt(number) - 1);
        if($this.html() === '0') $this.remove();
    })
}, 1000);
```

And you can do: `if(parseInt($this.html(), 10) === 0) $this.remove();` instead if you want to really verify that it's a number.

Also as [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21055879/573634) includes, saying `$this.html(parseInt(number, 10) - 1);` is better than just `$this.html(parseInt(number) - 1);` as it tells JS that it's a base 10 (decimal) number and will help prevent possible problems with your code.

Comment: haha, that was what I was typing as you updated it. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this.html(parseInt(number) - 1);
if($this.html() == 0){
    $this.remove();
}
```

Also why `$this = $(this)`? Why don't you just use `$(this)`?

Comment: `$this.html(parseInt(number)) == 0` won't work. You are comparing a jQuery object against 0. *"Also why `$this = $(this)`?"* To avoid calling `$` multiple times. It's a quite common practice.

Comment: @adeneo has a better solution.